# Change password in windows server? Ctrl + Alt + Del is not working through OSK; Getting error: "To use the commands available when you press ..."

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I was unable to change my windows server 2016 password through OSK. I was getting this below error:

> To use the commands available when you press Ctrl + Alt + Del, click
> your user title and choose an option.

I spent so much time and later I found answer in microsoft.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This way helped me for Windows Server 2016 RDP session:

1. Click Start.
2. Type "osk" and open the "*On Screen Keyboard*".
3. Once its open, hold **Ctrl** + **Alt** on your ***Physical Keyboard***, then click on the **Del** key in the ***On Screen Keyboard***.

That's it. This worked for me.

Thanks to: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/user-tile/8faf8cb6-5a8c-43cf-abf6-00de00a80fe5